# Extremely long time for terminal (or item2) to start up

Tags: python, terminal, iterm2

I am using an iMac. Usually, it took about 3 seconds for a new terminal to get ready. Several days ago, the start-up for the terminal or item2 became several minutes. While waiting, on top of the terminal is a title showing "python", but once it gets ready, it shows "-zsh", as shown in the picture below.[image: screen capture]

I solved this problem by deleting the .zshrc file which contains commands for anaconda initialization (see below). I still wonder why the lag happens and should I just delete this? Any consequence?

## >>> conda initialize >>>

## !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!

__conda_setup="$('/Users/C/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
eval "$__conda_setup"
else
if [ -f "/Users/C/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
. "/Users/C/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
else
export PATH="/Users/C/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
fi
fi
unset __conda_setup

## <<< conda initialize <<<

Comment: You can experiment by deleting various lines from .zshrc, and measure the startup time. You can also share your findings by answering  your own question on this site.

Comment: A terminal on my Linux computer starts and displays a prompt in less than 0.5 seconds. Even 3 seconds sounds like way too much.

Comment: While you see only the cursor in the new terminal window, it is doing shell (Zsh) startup. If you rename all Zsh config files, e.g. .zshrc and .zshenv, you can see how fast it can get. Please note that there are config files in /etc as well.